# pandas join string and number columns from same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge a Two columns in a database:

The two columns are

```
A
1 
2 
Na
Na

B
Na 
Na 
C
Na
```

Output

```
D 
1
2
C 
Na
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['D'] = df['A'].combine_first(df['B'])
```

Or:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])
```

**Notice**:

*If one column is numeric and another not, get mixed `types` and some functions can be broken.*

Comment: Thank you so much, but when I am trying to save to excel. It works fine and gets saved but in excel a warning appears in that column saying

"Number formatted as text" 
How to get rid of it, any help?

Comment: This is exactly what say notice - it is not recommnded, but if really need it, ignore warning.

Answer (score 3):

Use `combine_first`

```
df.A.combine_first(df.B)
```

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2, np.nan, np.nan], B=[np.nan, np.nan, 'C', np.nan]))
```

Then

```
df.A.combine_first(df.B)

0      1
1      2
2      C
3    NaN
Name: A, dtype: object
```

You can assign it to a new column `'C'`

```
df.assign(C=df.A.combine_first(df.B))

     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN    1
1  2.0  NaN    2
2  NaN    C    C
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and making it presentable. 
Any idea how to convert the mixed types into one single type?

Comment: @Abul yes!  but this question was about merging columns.  I suggest you ask another question.  We appreciate questions because they present more opportunities to earn upvotes.  :-)